# How to get rid of welcome screens for the guest user in Windows 11 for Education?

Tags: windows-11, imaging, shared-access

Simple thing really: I successfully created a Windows 11 Education setup with "Shared PC" settings, i.e. there's a guest user who can logon anonymously and whose changes will be reverted after every logout. This means, however, that every application under the sun (and Windows itself) thinks that the user has to be presented with their various welcome screens.

Windows shows me the "Touch gesture tips!" screen directly after logon
Office presents the "Read this and then press Accept for data privacy stuff" screen
Edge / Firefox / ... show me their: "Hey, you're new here! Click through these 10 screens first!" stuff
And so on.

I've been unable to find anything to fix this because as soon as I combine the words "disable" and "guest account" in any kind of way, every search engine thinks that I want to disable the guest account.

So, what do I need to do to make those welcome screens go away?

Comment: First, each and every application will differ, so you'll need to list each and every application you want to do this to, BUT, many of these steps are documented online, so you need to do some research first because you can answer most of these yourself. Second, the basic idea is that you'll need to set the state the profile is reset back to is a state where the application's settings reflect whatever changes you need made to prevent these popups. I haven't done this with Windows 11, but with other versions you could adjust these things in the ntuser.dat file in the Default user folder.

Comment: I don’t use the Education version but guest accounts were removed from Windows quite a long time ago.  Is that maybe the reason ?

Comment: Are you actually using the Guest account, which I thought no longer existed for at least 8 years, or you talking about new user accounts with the same permissions as the Guest account? Firefox and Edge welcome pages can be disabled with various levels of success. Office can be configure not to show new user notifications through a group policy.

Comment: It's called the "Guest" account under Windows 11 Education and can be enabled by using the Windows Configuration Designer, under "SharedPC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the various suggestions on registry / policy settings you find on the internet don't work out of the box. Because while there are settings regarding Edge in the policy editor, these are **not** applied to Edge.

What you need to do is to download are the Policy Rules on the [Microsoft Edge for Business page](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/edge/business/download?form=MA13FJ) (click the link *below* the huge "Download" button, you want the policies), extract the folder and then copy the adml files over to the Windows/PolicyDefinitions folder. You want to copy both the "main" adml files and the ones in the language you need (e.g. "en-US") to their corresponding folders.

After you've done that, opening gpedit.msc should now show a new entry for Edge directly under Administrative Templates. And only what you configure **here** will apply to a new user.
Firefox has such GPOs for download as well, Office nominally also but weirdly enough, has only a dearth of options which do not allow for disabling the "New user, who dis?" screen.
Disabling the "Touch Tips" screen also hasn't met success either. Well at least I got 50% of what I wanted.

You can check if policies have been applied correctly to Edge by going to edge://policies - that's what tipped me off to the policy settings under `AdministrativeTemplates/Windows Components/Microsoft Edge` not being picked up - because whatever I changed there wouldn't show up.